# How to pass hard-coded youtube-dl code & tkinter variable to command line

Tags: python-3.x, variables, tkinter, command-line, youtube-dl

I am attempting to paste the youtube video URL into the tkinter GUI text box, and have the 'Browse' button initiate a subprocess call that takes a hard-coded youtube-dl code, and adds the text box URL.
I can't seem to pass the hard-coded Youtube-dl code, and variable to command line.

Googled multiple things to find answers but can't seem to find any...

```
from tkinter import *
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
import os
import subprocess


root = Tk()
root.geometry("900x800")    
Title = root.title( "JJ's Youtube Downloader")
PathTextBox = Text(root,height =  2)
PathTextBox.grid(row = 4,column = 1,columnspan = 2)
path = PathTextBox.get('1.0',END)
def download():
    import subprocess
    subprocess.call(["youtube-dl -x --audio-format mp3 ", path])


BrowseButton = Button(root,text="Browse ",command = download)
BrowseButton.grid(row = 2,column = 2)

root.configure(background='ivory2')
HeadLabel1 = Label(root,text="Image ")
HeadLabel1.grid(row = 1,column = 1,sticky=(E))
HeadLabel2 = Label(root,text="Reader ")
HeadLabel2.grid(row = 1,column = 2,sticky=(W))
InputLabel = Label(root,text = "INPUT IMAGE")
InputLabel.grid(row = 2, column = 1)


PathLabel = Label(root,text = "Path:")
PathLabel.grid(row = 3,column = 1,sticky=(W))



DataLabel = Label(root,text = "DATA IN IMAGE:")
DataLabel.grid(row = 6,column = 1,sticky=(W+E+N+S))
ResultTextBox = Text(root,height = 30,padx = 1, pady = 1)
ResultTextBox.grid(row = 7,column = 1,columnspan = 4,padx=3, 
pady=3,sticky=W+E+N+S)

root.mainloop()
```

ERROR CODE I'M RECEIVING
    Exception in Tkinter callback
    Traceback (most recent call last):
 File 
"C:\Users\hutch\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\tkinter__init__.py", line 1705, in **call**
    return self.func(*args)
  File "C:\Users\hutch\Downloads\Desktop\PythonPrograms\YoutubeDownloader.py", line 17, in download
    subprocess.call(["youtube-dl -x --audio-format mp3 ", path])
  File "C:\Users\hutch\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\subprocess.py", line 323, in call
    with Popen(*popenargs, **kwargs) as p:
  File "C:\Users\hutch\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\subprocess.py", line 775, in **init**
    restore_signals, start_new_session)
  File "C:\Users\hutch\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\subprocess.py", line 1178, in _execute_child
    startupinfo)
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified

Comment: Sorry about the error code not pasting well...

Comment: Try `subprocess.call(["youtube-dl", "-x", "--audio-format", "mp3", path])`. Or, as youtube-dl is a python program, you can just [import it](https://github.com/ytdl-org/youtube-dl/blob/master/README.md#embedding-youtube-dl).

Answer (score 0):

Instead of needing to call youtube-dl as a subprocess, you can [import youtube-dl itself direct from PyPI](https://pypi.org/project/youtube_dl/) and use it like you would any other Python library.

You can add it to your Python environment by running `pip install youtube_dl` in your terminal/command prompt, and then call `YoutubeDL.download()` from within your script. To use the command-line arguments you've included in your subprocess string, you can try the following (This example is slightly modified from the [documentation](https://github.com/ytdl-org/youtube-dl/blob/master/README.md#embedding-youtube-dl), it will download the audio track from your video, then convert to MP3, doing pretty much the same thing as defining `-x` in your command line arguments)

```
import youtube_dl

ydl_opts = {
    'format': 'bestaudio/best',
    'postprocessors': [{
        'key': 'FFmpegExtractAudio',
        'preferredcodec': 'mp3',
        'preferredquality': '192',
    }]
}
with youtube_dl.YoutubeDL(ydl_opts) as ydl:
    ydl.download([path])
```

Comment: Thanks @Hoppeduppeanut ! The code runs, but two command windows pop up for a millisecond and then disappear... The song doesn't download to the usual folder... I can't see what the command windows say because they disappear too quickly.

Comment: I'll need to do some investigation once I'm able to use an interpreter again, but I'd say check the path where you're running your script and see if it's ended up in there.